# Hibernate data jpa считывает таблицы БД, но не сохраняет запись

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Приложение Spring Boot, в интерфейсе для работы с БД наследую класс "JpaRepository":

```
@Repository
public interface UserDataRepository extends JpaRepository<UserData,Long> {

    List<UserData> findAllBy();
    Optional<UserData> findByIdRUserData(Long id);
    UserData findByUser(User user);

    void deleteById(Long id);
}
```

Все методы `find` срабатывают нормально, а вот на методе `save` "JpaRepository" выдает не очень понятное исключение, что таблицы не существует:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db_users.hibernate_sequence'
> doesn't exist     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]     at
> ...
>
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: error
> performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated
> work
>
> > ```
> > at
> > ```
>
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
>
> > ```
> > at
> > ```
>
> > org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
> > Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
> > 'db_users.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist   at
> > com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
> > at
> > com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)

В чем причина такой ошибки и как она устраняется?

Код сущности:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="data_user")
public class UserData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Id_data_user")
    private Long idRUserData;

    @Column(name="INN")
    private  String INN;

    @Column(name="Full_name_company")
    private  String fullNameCompany;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userData")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_type_subject")
    private TypeSubject typeSubject;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_organizational_form")
    private OrganizationalForm organizationalForm;
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="Type_subject")
public class TypeSubject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="Id_type_subject")
    private int idTypeSubject;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private  String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "typeSubject")
    private List<UserData> userDataList;
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="Organizational_form")
public class OrganizationalForm {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="Id_organizational_form")
    private int idOrganizationalForm;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private  String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organizationalForm")
    private List<UserData> userDataList;
}
```

Сохранение:

```
serData userData=UserData.builder().INN("123654789012").fullNameCompany("OAO Romashka").typeSubject(typeSubjectService.findByIdTypeSubject(1).get())
            .organizationalForm(organizationalFormService.findByIdOrganizationalForm(1).get()).build();
    userDataService.save(userData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в генерации ключей записей, нужно поменять генерацию ключей с GenerationType.AUTO на GenerationType.IDENTITY. Более подробное описание здесь https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/